# What does this Capistrano error output mean?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, deployment, rvm, capistrano

I'm trying to configure Capistrano to deploy a Rails 3.2.14 app from my OS X system to a CentOS 6 VPS.

I have RVM gemsets on both machines called "ruby-1.9.3@rails_3_personal".

I have the capistrano and rvm/capistrano gems installed.

I made sure that the login user has required directory permissions on the target server.

When I run...

```
cap deploy:setup -d
```

I get this output...

```
        triggering load callbacks
      * 2013-09-02 14:06:45 executing `deploy:setup'
      * executing "mkdir -p /opt/deployed_rails_apps/my_app /opt/deployed_rails_apps/my_app/releases /opt/deployed_rails_apps/my_app/shared /opt/deployed_rails_apps/my_app/shared/system /opt/deployed_rails_apps/my_app/shared/log /opt/deployed_rails_apps/my_app/shared/pids"
    Preparing to execute command: "mkdir -p /opt/deployed_rails_apps/my_app /opt/deployed_rails_apps/my_app/releases /opt/deployed_rails_apps/my_app/shared /opt/deployed_rails_apps/my_app/shared/system /opt/deployed_rails_apps/my_app/shared/log /opt/deployed_rails_apps/my_app/shared/pids"
    Execute ([Yes], No, Abort) ?  |y|  y
        servers: ["my_domain.com"]
        [user_name@my_domain.com] executing command
     ** [out :: user_name@my_domain.com] /home/user_name/.rvm//scripts/selector: line 709: /db: No such file or directory
     ** [out :: user_name@my_domain.com] /home/user_name/.rvm//scripts/functions/db: line 18: /db: No such file or directory
    ** [out :: user_name@my_domain.com] /home/user_name/.rvm//scripts/functions/gemset: line 21: /db: No such file or directory
     ** [out :: user_name@my_domain.com] mkdir: cannot create directory `/ruby-1.9.3-p448': Permission denied
     ** [out :: user_name@my_domain.com] 
     ** [out :: user_name@my_domain.com] Error: RVM was unable to use 'ruby-1.9.3-p448@rails_3_personal'
        command finished in 388ms
    failed: "rvm_path=$HOME/.rvm/ $HOME/.rvm/bin/rvm-shell 'ruby-1.9.3-p448@rails_3_personal' -c 'mkdir -p /opt/deployed_rails_apps/my_app /opt/deployed_rails_apps/my_app/releases /opt/deployed_rails_apps/my_app/shared /opt/deployed_rails_apps/my_app/shared/system /opt/deployed_rails_apps/my_app/shared/log /opt/deployed_rails_apps/my_app/shared/pids'" on user_name@my_domain.com
```

- Why is Capistrano trying to create `/ruby-1.9.3-p448`?
- And what does this error mean? (And the other two like it?) The path isn't even a valid path ("`//`").

  ```
       ** [out :: user_name@my_domain.com] /home/user_name/.rvm//scripts/selector: line 709: /db: No such file
  ```
- Also... "`Error: RVM was unable to use 'ruby-1.9.3-p448@rails_3_personal'`"

  Ok, "Unable to use." Why though? And how can I fix it?

Here is my `deploy.rb`...

```
require "bundler/capistrano"

require "rvm/capistrano"

set :rvm_ruby_string, 'ruby-1.9.3-p448@rails_3_personal'

set :rvm_type, :user

set :application, 'my_app'

set :repository, 'git@github.com:GithubUser/my_app.git'

set :deploy_to, "/opt/deployed_rails_apps/#{application}"

set :use_sudo, false

set :scm, "git"
set :branch, "master"

set :user, 'user_name'

set :deploy_via, :remote_cache

# Keep only 5 releases --------------------------------
set :keep_releases, 5
after "deploy:update", "deploy:cleanup"
# -----------------------------------------------------

load 'deploy/assets'

role :app, 'user_name@my_domain.com'
role :web, 'user_name@my_domain.com'

namespace :deploy do

  task :start, :roles => :app do
    run "touch #{current_release}/tmp/restart.txt"
  end

  task :stop, :roles => :app do
    # Do nothing.
  end

  desc "Restart Application"
  task :restart, :roles => :app do
    run "touch #{current_release}/tmp/restart.txt"
  end

end
```

Comment: capistrano is failing to switch to the correct ruby version (and of course you know that). Your RVM is a system-wide installation? If not, you might need to set the correct user in capistrano, with `set :user, "youruser"`.

Comment: Yes, I see the part where it says, "Error: RVM was unable to use 'ruby-1.9.3-p448@rails_3_personal'". So, agreed -- that's one problem that's happening here. I just don't know what to do about it. How can I fix it? I logged in to the target machine and confirmed that `rvm use ruby-1.9.3-p448@rails_3_personal` works as expected. Thank you for the suggestion. I did add `set :user, 'user_name'` in my `deploy.rb`, but I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: This looks like a bug in RVM, you should open ticket here: https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues

Comment: What's up with the close vote?

Comment: @mpapis [Done](https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues/2186).

Comment: the close vote is because it's a bug not a question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the problem is actually with this scripts:

```
 ** [out :: user_name@my_domain.com] /home/user_name/.rvm//scripts/selector: line 709: /db: No such file or directory
```

witch seems to be called in your `require "rvm/capistrano"`. You can try comment that and set the paths manually:

```
set :default_environment, {
    'PATH' => PATH,
    'GEM_HOME'     => GEM_HOME,
    'GEM_PATH'     => GEM_PATH,
}
```

To see your values, you can see `rvm info` after switch to your gemset.

Comment: Alright, thanks. I commented out `require "rvm/capistrano"` and explicitly set `:default_environment` as you suggested and now `cap deploy:setup` completes without errors. I so that fixed it. Thank you very much. I still don't understand what the problem was, though.

Comment: @Ethan Glad it worked, unfortunately I also have no clue for the real problem. Yet this workaround should do.

Answer (score 0):

this was a bug and is fixed with https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues/2186

it is required to update to latest version of rvm on the server:

```
rvm get head
```

Comment: I updated to the latest as you advised. I'm still getting the same error as described in my original question.

Comment: you need to update rvm on server not locally, please show the new output - it never is the same

Comment: Hi @mpapis. Thanks for the help. I updated both. I'm getting a different error now, as [noted](https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues/2186) on the rvm-capistrano Github issue tracker -- https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues/2186. It may be a Capistrano error.